# Ampscript and SSJS SOAP Call and read XML

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, xmlparsing

I'm trying to make a soap post and get a rowset but I think that my xpath is bad-constructed.

```
%%[
VAR @xml
]%%

<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

    var url = 'http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/ovcservweb/OVCSWLocalizacionRC/OVCCallejero.asmx';
    var contentType = 'text/xml';
    var payload = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body /></soap:Envelope>'; 
    var headerNames = ["SOAPAction"];
    var headerValues = ["http://tempuri.org/OVCServWeb/OVCCallejero/ConsultaProvincia"];
    var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);

    var xml = result.Response[0];

    Variable.SetValue("@xml", xml);
</script>
%%[
 SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml, ' xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/"',"")
 SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml, ' xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/"',"")
 SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml, ' xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/"',"")
 SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml, ' xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/"',"")
 SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml, ' xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/"',"")
 SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml, ' xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/"',"")
 SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml, ' xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/"',"")
 SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml, ' xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/"',"")

 SET @res = BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, "/Provincias/consulta_provinciero/provinciero/prov/np", 1)
 SET @rowCount =  RowCount(@res)
 outputLine (concat(@rowCount))
```

That outputLine always is zero but there is more than 40 elements

Why am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Xpath issue,

just putting my xpath as

```
"//Provincias/consulta_provinciero/provinciero/prov/np"
```

problem solved